# How can I redirect one 'vanity' domain to another domain via DNS?

Tags: url, redirect, dns, subdomain

I have a domain for my 'vanity urls', lets calls it `ample.co`, and the subdomain `ex.ample.co` is used for the vanity urls (using Bitly). The address `ex.ample.co` via Bitly redirects to `example.com`, the main website/domain.

Using the DNS setup from registrar, how can I redirect `ample.co` to `example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use dns resolving, there will be an option in the control panel of the domain registrar to use domain forwarding feature. You can use that.

Comment: what exactly you mean by Domain registrar ?

Comment: domain registrar (or domain seller) is the company where you buy your domain